# Elastic Search analyzing fields and Kibana Graphs Legends

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I'm using elasticsearch 1.5.2 and Kibana 4.0.3.

I'm having a problem with the analyzers, using the default one the legends in the kibana graphs split the field by &, / and -.
Which is the default behavior.
I've tried setting the fields to not_analyzed and then the kibana legends display fine and the grouping in the graphs works are I want, by field.
The problem is that the wildcard doesn't work with the search, to search a field you need to use the exact value.

I haven't been able to find an analyzer or a tokenizer that would preserver the field as it is.

Any ideas on how could I use the not_analyzed but still have the search as when it's analyzed?

Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a multi-field (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) to achieve what you want.

For example:

```
"title": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
    }
}
```

You'd then use `title:whatever` to search and `title.raw` in the kibana panel to get the correct legend behavior.

Comment: Thanks, going to try that :-)